# How to set the row background color in Kendo UI Grid?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I have grid with 21 rows. My requirement is to set some of  rows background color is Light Green(like 1,5,13 rows) is this possible to achieve.

```
$("#gridSellIn")
     .kendoGrid({
         width: 1500,
         dataSource: data.d,
         resizable: true,
         selectable: true,                                
         rowTemplate: kendo.template($("#SellInrowTemplate").html()),
                            height: 500,
                            columns: [
                                            { title: 'RevProduct Name', field: 'ProductName', width: '22%', sortable: true },
                                            { title: 'Actuals', field: 'Actual', width: '8%', sortable: true },

                                      ]
                        });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use jQuery to set any CSS property of any HTML element. This includes table rows and background color. Here is something to get you started:

```
$("#gridSellIn tr").css("background-color", "red");
```

Refer to the jQuery documentation for further info:

- jQuery [css](http://api.jquery.com/css/)
- jQuery [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) (check [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) and [nth-child()](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/))

Comment: how to remove this red color again

Answer (score 12):

You could try this conditional method

```
var grid = $("#gridSellIn").data("kendoGrid");
var data = grid.dataSource.data();
$.each(data, function (i, row) {
  if (row.ProductName == 'Apples')
     $('tr[data-uid="' + row.uid + '"] ').css("background-color", "green");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

On databound event you can :

```js
var rows = e.sender.tbody.children();
 
for (var j = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {
    var row = $(rows[j]);
    var dataItem = e.sender.dataItem(row);
 
    if (dataItem.get("PropertyName") != 0) {
        row.addClass("someCssColorClass");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
    var data = grid.dataSource.data();
    // the section below is using JQuery each function to loop
    // over the grid data then checking the row index if its an odd or even number
    //by finding the modulus of the number.
    // In this case i'm checking for odd number

    $.each(data, (i, row) => {        
        if (i % 2) {
            $('tr[data-uid="' + row.uid + '"]').css("background-color","rgb(247, 244, 244)");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you are using a row template:

```
rowTemplate: kendo.template($("#SellInrowTemplate").html())
```

If you have a value in your dataset that you are binding to the grid that determines that the row needs to be highlighted, you can set the color in the template as it is bound:

```
# if (data.columnvalue === condition) { #
<tr class="highlight">
#} else {#
<tr>
#} #
```